# R multidimensional matrix data acces from function

Tags: r

I'have the follow data type

```
dim(sampleData$mod)
# [1]   5   9   6   7  73 144
```

and i need to extract this data

```
t1 <- as.vector(sampleData$mod[,,,1,,])
```

The problem is that i need a function to get the data from any of the variable dimension

I want some like this:

```
sampleData$mod[tmp]
```

and i have this

```
sampleData$mod[,,,1,,]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from the question, something like the following might be helpful:

```
ff = function(array, dims, inds)
{
    dimseq = lapply(dim(array), seq_len)
    dimseq[dims] = inds 
    do.call("[", c(list(array), dimseq))
}   

ar = array(seq_len(3*2*4*3*5), c(3,2,4,3,5))
identical(ar[, , 1, , ], ff(ar, 3, 1))
#[1] TRUE
identical(ar[, 1, , 2, 1], ff(ar, c(2, 4, 5), c(1, 2, 1)))
#[1] TRUE
identical(ar[, 1, , 2:3, c(1, 3)], ff(ar, c(2, 4, 5), list(1, 2:3, c(1, 3))))
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to run 6 nested `for` loops (one for each dimension), and you put the values one after the other on a vector `vec`. Then you do `sampleData$mod=vec`.

Note that you shoud initialise a vector as `vec=rep(0, 5*9*6*7*73*144)` and then put values into it, rather that doing `c(vec, new_value)` or you will have a huge overhead due to vector resizing.